# Why DB:select work and DB::table doesn't work?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a problem with `DB:table` of Laravel.
I use PostgreSQL and it doesn't work.
This is my query:

```
$User = Db::table('immobilier.prg_programmes as prog')
   ->select('select prg_libelle')
   ->join(' immobilier.liaisons_rol_act_tyr_prg ','immobilier.liaisons_rol_act_tyr_prg.prg_id','=','immobilier.prg_programmes.prg_id')
   ->join('immobilier.liaisons_rol_act as ra','b.rol_act_id','=','ra.rol_act_id ')
   ->join(' immobilier.act_acteurs as act','ra.act_id','=','act.act_id  ')
   ->join(' immobilier.tra_tranches as tra','prog.prg_id','=','tra.prg_id  ')
   ->get();
```

But with `DB:select` it works:

```
$user = DB::select('select prg_libelle as nom_programme,prog.prg_id ,act_libelle as nom_promotteur, tra_libelle as nom_tranche
   from  immobilier.prg_programmes as prog
   inner join  immobilier.liaisons_rol_act_tyr_prg as b  on b.prg_id =prog.prg_id
   inner join  immobilier.liaisons_rol_act as ra on b.rol_act_id =ra.rol_act_id 
   inner join  immobilier.act_acteurs as act on ra.act_id =act.act_id 
   inner join immobilier.tra_tranches as tra on prog.prg_id = tra.prg_id 
   order by prog.prg_id ASC;
   ');
```

I need to use `DB:table` to make pagination.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What errors do you get ?

Comment: If you replace `get()` to `toSql()` you can see what SQL query is actually generated and compare it with what you need. Might help finding what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your join instruction, you use the alias "b" that is never declared.

```
->join('immobilier.liaisons_rol_act as ra','b.rol_act_id','=','ra.rol_act_id ')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `select` method' arguments are the columns you want to actually select. It must not include the `select` keyword:

```
$User = Db::table('immobilier.prg_programmes as prog')
   ->select(['prg_libelle'])
   ->join('immobilier.liaisons_rol_act_tyr_prg ', 'immobilier.liaisons_rol_act_tyr_prg.prg_id','=','immobilier.prg_programmes.prg_id')
   ->join('immobilier.liaisons_rol_act as ra','b.rol_act_id','=','ra.rol_act_id ')
   ->join('immobilier.act_acteurs as act','ra.act_id','=','act.act_id  ')
   ->join('immobilier.tra_tranches as tra','prog.prg_id','=','tra.prg_id  ')
   ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still get this error:SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERREUR: la relation « immobilier.liaisons_rol_act_tyr_prg » n'existe pas LINE 1:

Comment: Does the table exist?

Answer (score 0):

you should change this section `->select('select prg_libelle')` to:

`->select('prg_libelle')` or

`->selectRaw('prg_libelle')`